# Creating useable custom-font family on a site in CSS for a specific use case

Tags: css, formatting, html

How can I create a custom font family that can be used inside of <span></span> tags, and only within those tags and not site wide?

My end goal is to be able to use this within a specific area of the site, and not anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the span a class and assign font-family css properties to it, IE:

```
<span class="specialFont">Hello</span>
```

then in your css:

```
.specialFont {
    font-family: verdana;
 }
```

As per your comment, to use custom fonts you can use this, HOWEVER keep in mind this isn't supported in all browsers:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: CustomFont;
   src: URL('/fonts/myfont.otf'); 
}

.specialFont { 
     font-family: CustomFont;
}
```

Comment: If the font-family is non-standard, aka a custom font, how would I define that custom font-family?  this explains the span part, but not the definition of the custom font-family.

Comment: Does Firefox, IE8+, and/or Opera support this?

Comment: I think they all do except IE ... (figures)

Comment: Does this support true type fonts?

Comment: Ah, I had to clear the cache that my site has.  Now it works, thanks!